# Chrome issue: Font awesome in ul li a breaks padding

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, zurb-foundation, font-awesome

Strange issue... have tested in Safari, Opera, FF, IE and all seem fine - first time to be honest I have had an issue with Chrome alone!

Foundation 6 framework.

In my top nav, one item has a background and font awesome icon.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance.

[FF example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBkL9.png)
[Chrome Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iuzwx.png)

HTML:

```html
<div class="title-bar">
    <div class="title-bar-left">
        <span class="title-bar-title"><img src="{$ThemeDir}/images/logoNav.png" alt="$SiteConfig.Title"/></span>
    </div>
    <div class="title-bar-right">
        <ul class="large-horizontal main-menu">
            <% loop Menu(1) %>
            <li class="menu-item<% if $LinkingMode == "current" || $LinkingMode == "section" %> active<% end_if %>">
                <a href="$Link" title="Go to $Title.ATT">$MenuTitle</a>
                <% if $Children %>
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <% loop $Children %>
                    <li class="<% if $LinkingMode == "current" || $LinkingMode == "section" %>active<% end_if %>">
                        <a href="$Link" title="Go to $Title.ATT"> $MenuTitle</a>
                    </li>
                    <% end_loop %>
                </ul>
                <% end_if %>
            </li>
            <% end_loop %>
            <li class="menu-item client-login"><a href="#" class="client-login-button" title="Go go Client Login">Client Login <i class="fa fa-users"></i></a></li>
        </ul>

        <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-open="offCanvas"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```css
// custom menu button

li.menu-item.client-login{
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(8,79,123,0.7);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 #3b3b3b;
 padding: 1.2rem;
 padding-top: 5rem;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px 0 #3b3b3b;
 border-radius: 0 0 0.5rem 0.5rem;
 @include transition(background-color 0.3s ease);
 &:hover{
  background-color: rgba(8,79,123,1);
 }

 a{
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
 }
}

.main-menu li.menu-item.client-login a{

 color: $white;
 font-weight: 600;
 &:hover{
  color:$white;
 } 
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

Font awesome has `display:inline-block;` on the i element.

A simple override to `display:inline;` was all that was required

Answer (score 0):

use CDN instead of storing that file locally to your project and make sure that you are including jquery before fontawesome CDN to your project